The js_set does not work when setting a variable from function
This is the first time me playing with Nginx & njs.
I am trying to find a way to get the value from the JSON request and pass it as a new header to the upstream.
I have the following function:
function extract (r) {
   var json = JSON.parse(r.requestText);
   var sessionid = json["sessionId"];
   return sessionid;
}

And then:
js_set $sessionid http.extract;

I cannot assign the result of my function to the $sessionid variable which then I will use to pass to the upstream server:
proxy_set_header Cookie "mycookie=$sessionid";

When I send the curl command, the /var/log/nginx/error.log gives me:
2024/11/28 01:10:20 [error] 64724#64724: *455 js exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token at position 0
    at JSON.parse (native)
    at extract_sessionid (/etc/nginx/njs/http.js:3)

The r.requestText is a JSON:
{ "sessionId":"F105" }

The value "F105" would be used to proxy add header.
Any idea?
Thank you.

As noted in their documentation, the requestBuffer/requestText properties are available only in the js_content directive. Still, there is no reason to give up :) Here are two methods that should help you achieve the result you're looking for.

Analyze the requestText property using the js_content location content handler and then jump to another location for further request processing:
nginx.conf
js_import /path/to/extract_json_field.js;
server {
    ...
    location / {
        # `$session_id` variable needs to be preinitialized
        set $session_id "";
        js_content extract_json_field.parse_request_text;
    }
    location @main {
        ... # all the other `proxy_set_header` directives, etc.
        proxy_set_header Cookie "mycookie=$session_id";
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}

extract_json_field.js
function parse_request_text(r) {
    try {
        let json = JSON.parse(r.requestText);
        r.variables.session_id = json['sessionId'] || '';
    } catch (e) {
        r.error('JSON.parse exception');
    }
    r.internalRedirect('@main');
}

export default { parse_request_text }


Use the mirror directive to populate $request_body built-in nginx variable during the PREACCESS request processing phase. This allows you to use r.variables.request_body in place of the requestText property (inspired by this example):
nginx.conf
js_import /path/to/extract_json_field.js;
server {
    ...
    js_set $session_id extract_field.parse_request_body;
    location / {
        ... # all the other `proxy_set_header` directives, etc.
        proxy_set_header Cookie "mycookie=$session_id";
        mirror /_get_request_body;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
    # Dummy location used to populate `$request_body` variable
    location /_get_request_body {
        internal;
        return 204;
    }
}

extract_json_field.js
function parse_request_body(r) {
    let json = {};
    try {
        json = JSON.parse(r.variables.request_body);
    } catch (e) {
        r.error('JSON.parse exception');
    }
    return json['sessionId'] || '';
}

export default { parse_request_body }



If you'd like njs, I can recommend two excellent resources:

njs examples GitHub repository.
The F5 nginx blog post "Harnessing the Power and Convenience of JavaScript for Each Request with the NGINX JavaScript Module", particularly the "Use Cases for the NGINX JavaScript Module" links collection at the end.


Hi, do you any idea how to use that sessionId extracted from the request to be used for session affinity? Instead of letting Nginx create the cookie, is it possible to just configure Nginx to use your custom cookie?

@Fergara Read the "HTTP Load Balancing" article. I think the hash load-balancing method is what you should try first; something like upstream backend { hash $session_id consistent; ... }
